# iCloud files on the iPad 'undownload' after being unused for a while

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud

I have an iPad Pro running iOS 12.2. I manage my files through the Files manager available (mostly PDFs). After a period of non-use, the local copies get removed and a cloud sign appears. The redownload cannot be done all together and each file has to be redownloaded separately. I need my lecture slides to stay in as a local copy. I have found no setting with optimize storage that would do this to files.

Can I influence a set of files to remain available for offline / cached access if they are stored in iCloud files?